# Pegando um único valor parse PHP

Tags: php, html, array, dom, libcurl

```
$ch = curl_init('site');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050414 Firefox/1.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'x.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'x.txt');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$link = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
  # Mostrar todos os elemento que estiver dentro da tag href


$x = $link->getAttribute('href'); // exibi todos os conteudo dentro do href !
// pegar apenas o link completo
#https://www.site.com/checkout.asp?ref=fvFDGND2MYQ

///
echo $x;
```

poem dessa forma eu consigo pegar todos os links do html recebido do cURL

http://prntscr.com/5icnbf

e para mim pegar apenas o https://www.site.com/checkout.asp?ref=fvFDGND2MYQ ? apenas esse link ?

Answer (score 1):

Se queres um *link* em particular, podes verificar o conteúdo do mesmo para saberes se é de facto o que pretendes:

```php
// ...
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {

  /* Verifica se é o link que eu quero
   */
  $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
  if (strpos($href, "checkout.asp?ref=") !== FALSE) {
    $x = $href;  // guarda o link
    break;       // sair do ciclo
  }
}
```

Para verificar, o que foi feito foi verificar se existe a expressão `checkout.asp?ref=` no *link* a ser processado, recorrendo à função [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Deverás alterar a expressão caso procures outro *link* que não o que tens na pergunta.

Podes ver um exemplo a funcionar no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/JHJ2yb) combinado com o teu problema anterior.

Comment: :)) Agora sim peguei só o link que preciso muito obrigado ...